# How to update a list of dictionaries without a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of **N** dictionaries, along with a list of **N** strings. For each dictionary in the former, I would like to append/update a key-value pair with the corresponding string from the later.

For example:

```py
names = [{'First':'John','Last':'Doe'} , {'First':'Jane','Last':'Doe'}]
ages = ['21','32']
```

The following loop works:

```py
for i,j in zip(names,ages):
    i.update({'Age':j})
    print(i)
```

Partly for the intellectual challenge, but partly to accommodate eventual parallel processing, I would like to solve the same problem without a loop. Neither of my two attempts worked; both returned a list of **None** types:

First attempt:

```py
f = lambda x: x[0].update({'Age':x[1]})
out = map(f,zip(names,ages))
for i in out: print(i)
```

Second attempt:

```py
out = (i.update({'Age':j}) for i,j in zip(names,ages))
for i in out: print(i)
```

What gives?

Comment: Both of your attempts use "loops"?

Comment: `d.update()` mutates `d` and returns `None`. You could technically do `f = lambda x: x[0].update({'Age':x[1]}) and x[0]` but that's just silly.

Comment: `update()` doesn't return anything. The way you're doing it, you should see the changes if you investigate `names` after doing your `map` or comprehension; but `out` will just be a list/tuple of Nones.

Comment: Fair point: So if `update` doesn't return anything, then what's the better alternative? Can I use a lambda function to return a dictionary comprehension?

Comment: Is a comprehension somehow not a "loop" to you?

Comment: this isn't a "bad" question, but your efforts are a bit misguided.  A for-loop is fine here.

Comment: @IainShelvington Other than to print the values, neither of my two solutions uses a loop; the first creates a map object, the second creates a generator function.

Comment: @anon01 A for-loop doesn't play well with parallel processing. That's my eventual use case.

Comment: @Aboottogo how do you think both of those constructs are implemented?

Comment: what doesn't play well?  these look to be trivially paralellizable

Comment: @IainShelvington I think they are conceptually identical, but computationally different. Generators yield an object that is not evaluated at the time it's yielded; loops evaluate every iteration. Loops also store more in memory. When I work with data in the TBs, I try my hardest to avoid loops.

Comment: @anon01 I'd have to see it to believe it.

Comment: @Aboottogo Everything you have just described uses some form of loop. "Loops also store more in memory" if you are referring to list comprehensions vs generators then yes generators use less memory than list comprehensions but they both still use "loops". Your original question is regarding updating a dictionary of which the result cannot be a generator as that would not make sense because any iteration could change any of the keys

Comment: @IainShelvington It makes sense to me, but then again that's why I'm here with the question :)

Comment: @Aboottogo can you give an example of the multiprocessing call that you want to make? You want an iterable that yields user and age data in a memory efficient way? Your question is named poorly

Comment: @IainShelvington The example here is probably too simple, but suppose more generally the task of of merging two datasets L (left) and R (right), and then computing some statistic, f, on the merged data. The advantage of merging the data with a generator is that I can create a pool `pool = multiprocessing.Pool() ` and then `stat = pool.map(f,out)`. The disadvantage of a 'traditional' loop is that the intermediate step -- the merged data -- is held in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dict unpacking operator `**`, it should be possible to return a merged dict as the result of a map, *without* modifying the original at all.

```
f = lambda x: {**x[0], 'Age': x[1]}
out = map(f,zip(names,ages))
print(list(out))
# [{'First': 'John', 'Last': 'Doe', 'Age': '21'}, 
#  {'First': 'Jane', 'Last': 'Doe', 'Age': '32'}]
```

This is a slightly uncommon idiom that you can use to merge dicts on the fly. When it releases in a few months, Python 3.9 will be adding an overload for the `|` operator that would allow you to do something like `x[0] | {'Age': x[1]}` to achieve the same result more clearly, but for now this should serve your purposes.

This should make the solution easier to parallelize, though keep in mind a `for` loop can perfectly well be used for parallelization, as long as each element is independent of the others - you can just split the list into chunks and hand one chunk to each parallel process. The only benefit of *this* approach, as opposed to the one you're already using, is that the various parallel processes would be no longer writing to the same datastructure in memory.